# DevExpress GridView in LookUpEdit

Tags: devexpress, repositorylookupedit, gridlookupedit

I can add columns like this in GridView, but I don't know how to add RepositoryLookUpEdit. Would you help me with this topic? (I'm sorry for my bad English.)

```
DataTable DT = new DataTable();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DT.Columns.Add("IP", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        DT.Columns.Add("Port", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        DT.Columns.Add("Username", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        DT.Columns.Add("Password", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        DT.Columns.Add("Working?", Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));
    }

    private void btn_ekle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow dr = DT.NewRow();
        dr[0] = "Test";
        dr[1] = "Test";
        dr[2] = "Test";
        dr[3] = "Test";
        dr[4] = true;
        DT.Rows.Add(dr);

        dtg_goster.DataSource = DT;
        gridView1.PopulateColumns();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the RepositoryItemLookUpEdit's [Columns property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemLookUpEdit.Columns.property) to add/remove columns. This can be done at runtime:

```
lookUpEdit1.Properties.Columns.Add(new LookUpColumnInfo("FieldName", "Caption", 100)); //100 is width in pixels
```

Similar to what you are doing with the GridControl, you can also use the LookUpEdit's [PopulateColumns method](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemLookUpEdit.PopulateColumns.method) to create a column for each field in the data source. Note that you may need to also invoke the LookUpEdit's [ForceInitialize method](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemLookUpEdit.ForceInitialize.method) **before** you invoke the PopulateColumns method to ensure that the control is fully initialized.